# Как отправлять .pdf файлы с google диска через телеграм бот?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, google-drive

Я создал самого простого бота в Node.js, используя telegraf.js фреймворк. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на определенную команду, бот отправлял клиенту .pdf документ, расположенный на google диске (публичный доступ к документу открыл).

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

bot.command('dwnld', ctx => {
   bot.telegram.sendDocument(ctx.chat.id, 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EETTa6cruWH4i-pB6s-WnSuI4EZtEKY6/view?usp=sharing')
})

bot.launch()
```

Но при нажатии на созданную команду `dwnld` в телеграме Node.js выдаёт ошибку `Error: 400: Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content`. Ссылка на документ - рабочая. Подскажите, как мне добиться желаемого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открываем [документацию](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files):

> Отправка по URL-адресу
>
> При отправке по URL-адресу целевой файл должен иметь правильный тип
> MIME (например, audio/mpeg для SendAudio и т.д.). В sendDocument
> отправка по URL-адресу в настоящее время работает только для gif-,
> pdf- и zip-файлов.

Теперь смотрим что за файл вы пытаетесь послать:

```bsh
x@x:~ $ curl --head 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EETTa6cruWH4i-pB6s-WnSuI4EZtEKY6/view?usp=sharing'

HTTP/2 200 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-robots-tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
```

`content-type: text/html` говорит нам о том, что это - web-страница.

Для того чтобы "достичь желаемого" вы должны найти настоящую ссылку на файл и он должен быть `gif-, pdf- и zip-`. Если файл имеет другой тип то нужно или пользоваться другим методом, или загружать файлы (любые) через `multipart/form-data`

---

Что ж, теперь, когда мы во всём разобрались, нужно понять как нам узнать ссылку на нужный файл.

[In Google Drive, how can you link directly to “Download” a zip file and not view the contents?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30656)

> На данный момент вам нужно создать URL-адрес вручную.
>
> `https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YourIndividualID`
>
> Где YourIndividualID - это идентификатор соответствующего документа.
> Вы получаете его либо из URL-адреса, либо нажав Файл → Общий доступ и
> скопировав его из URL-адреса общего доступа.

Попробуем:

```
const { URL } = require('url');
...
const url = new URL('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EETTa6cruWH4i-pB6s-WnSuI4EZtEKY6/view?usp=sharing');
const urlpath = url.pathname.split(/\//);
const id = urlpath[urlpath.length - 2];
...
bot.telegram.sendDocument(
  ctx.chat.id,
  `https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${id}`
);
```

[image]

Comment: Да, всё работает! Немного удивило что `content-type: text/html`, несмотря на то что документ хранится в .pdf формате на google диске. Но теперь, если я правильно понимаю, эта ссылка лишь на html страницу для просмотра данного документа, а требуется, как вы и подсказали url самого файла для скачивания. Большое спасибо!